# Puppet PostgresQL management, Error: Puppet::Parser::AST::

Tags: postgresql, vagrant, puppet, provisioning

I'm using Vagrant and I'm trying to provision a VM using puppet. In the Vagrant file I configured VM db as follow:

```
config.vm.define "db" do |db|   
  db.vm.hostname = "db"    
  db.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.11.1.201", virtualbox__intnet: true
  db.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v| 
      v.memory = 1024 
  end 

  db.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host: 2221, id: 'ssh', auto_correct: true
    db.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5432, host: 2222
  db.ssh.forward_agent = true

       config.vm.provision :shell do |shell|
 shell.inline = "mkdir -p /etc/puppet/modules;
                 puppet module install puppetlabs-postgresql"

  end
       config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
    puppet.manifest_file = "site.pp"
    puppet.module_path = "puppet/modules"
  end
    end
end
```

As you can see I set the download of the modules using a vagrant shell command before the puppet provisioner runs. In this way I have downloaded the **puppetlabs-postgresql module** from puppet labs. I do not want to manage my database by creating classes in my site.pp file located in /puppet/manifests/site.pp. I want to have a module call database in /puppet/modules/database. What I have done so far is create an init.pp file in /puppet/modules/database. Below is the content of my init.pp file :

```
class database {
   class { 'postgresql::server':
  ip_mask_allow_all_users    => '0.0.0.0/0',
  listen_addresses           => '*',
  ipv4acls                   => ['hostssl all johndoe 192.168.0.0/24 cert'],
  postgres_password          => 'TPSrep0rt!',
}
}
```

And then in my /puppet/manifests/site.pp file i have included the database class as below :

```
node 'db' {
    include database
}
```

After the "vagrant up" command I get the error:

```
Error: Puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Could not find declared class postgresql::server at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-d1208595f982e4ac16b287f9bd398c89/database/manifests/init.pp:8 on node db.lan

==> db: Wrapped exception:

==> db: Could not find declared class postgresql::server

==> db: Error: Puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Could not find declared class postgresql::server at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-d1208595f982e4ac16b287f9bd398c89/database/manifests/init.pp:8 on node db.lan
```

What is the correct way to make use of the postgresql classes?

Comment: Can you ls your /puppet/modules/database directory ?

Answer (score 0):

It is weird feeling to read your code, especially the class database part.

can you set hieradata template for puppet module `postgresql`

something likes:

```
postgresql::server:
    ip_mask_allow_all_users: '0.0.0.0/0'
    listen_addresses: '*'
    ipv4acls: 
      - 'hostssl all johndoe 192.168.0.0/24 cert'
    postgres_password: 'TPSrep0rt!'
```

in node define,

```
node 'db' {
    include postgresql::server
}
```

manage the facters in `pp` file directly is not good practice.

Comment: i haven't understood where to place             
  postgresql::server:
    ip_mask_allow_all_users: '0.0.0.0/0'
    listen_addresses: '*'
    ipv4acls: 
      - 'hostssl all johndoe 192.168.0.0/24 cert'
    postgres_password: 'TPSrep0rt!'